# input a week, submit input and get all days in that week each in its own paragraph

Tags: javascript, date

I'd like users to to input a date, e.g '16 nov 2023', and get all dates in that specific week starting from monday which would return as example:

```
13 nov 2023
14 nov 2023
15 nov 2023
16 nov 2023
17 nov 2023
18 nov 2023
19 nov 2023
```

However I can't get around a way to bind then with my HTML page such that there's an `input` field where user enters a date and there's a submit button where upon selecting the dates are retrieved and displayed on the page each in its own paragraph tag.

This is the code I have but I'm failing to bind it with my page:

```
function days(current) {
  var week = [];
  // Starting Monday not Sunday 
  var first = current.getDate() - current.getDay() + 1;
  current.setDate(first);
  for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    week.push(new Date(+current));
    current.setDate(current.getDate()+1);
  }
  return week;
}

var input = document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = new Date(2023, 05, 13);
console.log('input: %s', input);
var result = document.getElementById('date1').innerHTML = days(input);
```

```
<input id="date" placeholder="type">
<button type="button" onclick="days()">press me</button>
```

Comment: What **exactly** is not working yet? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? That's so little code that debugging it, even with `console.log`, should not be that hard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To bind events to actions within the HTML you can use `addEventListener()`. In this case I would suggest listening for the `input` event of a `date` input. You can then take the value the user has chosen and pass it to your `days()` method to build the array of dates that you require.

From there you can create a HTML string to output each date in its own `<p>` tag which you can display within a container element, like this:

```js
const outputContainer = document.querySelector('#output-container');

function getDaysOfWeek(current) {
  var week = [];
  var first = current.getDate() - current.getDay() + 1;
  current.setDate(first);
  for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    week.push(new Date(+current));
    current.setDate(current.getDate() + 1);
  }
  return week;
}

document.querySelector('#date').addEventListener('input', e => {
  const weekDates = getDaysOfWeek(new Date(e.target.value));
  const html = weekDates.map(d => `<p>${d.toLocaleString()}</p>`).join('');
  outputContainer.innerHTML = html;
});
```

```css
p { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<input type="date" id="date" placeholder="type" />

<div id="output-container"></div>
```

Note that I used `toLocaleString()` to format the dates using the culture set in your browser. This can easily be updated to output the date in whatever format you require.

Comment: Hi McCrossan, if i may like that the dates be retrieved with the ability to post them to a database i understand i would need to have them wrapped in an input tag that will allow me to build a form to post each date to the relevant field. How will i proceed from your given solution. Thank you.

Comment: In that case you would just need to wrap the `input` element in my example in a `form` with a submit button. Any basic HTML form tutorial will show you how to do this. From there you would need to write your back-end code to receive the values and insert them in to your database. This again should be a trivial task, but would depend on whatever server side stack you're using.